# how to fix makefiles errors on veins project

Tags: makefile, omnet++, veins

when I build my veins project I have the following error :

```
    make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/mySimulation] Error 1
    Makefile:100: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/mySimulation' failed
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nai/omnet/omnetpp-5.2.1/myWorkspace/mySimulation/src'
    Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

the code portion of the makefiles where there is an error:
makefile in the src folder:

```
        @$(MKPATH) $O
```

make file in the out folder

```
       all: checkmakefiles
cd src && $(MAKE)
```

I cleaned the project and I rebuild it but it didn't work can anyone help me

Comment: You didn't show us the actual error.  The messages you showed only say that some operation make invoked as part of its recipe failed and exited with an error code 1.  You need to look at the error messages BEFORE this to see what failed and why.  In general, it's always best to look at the FIRST errors, not the last errors; sometimes the first error cascades and causes more errors.

Comment: you are right ! I only focused on the lines I copied on the post because they were highlited in red while the error was specified in all letters in the line at the top! thanks